Entity Framework keeps throwing Duplicate Primary Key Error Despite Rollback
Running on .NET Framework 4.6.2, I have a method that uses Entity Framework to insert a row into a SQL Server database table. It uses a transaction that gets rolled back if an error is thrown:
public async Task InsertReportRecord(Guid consultantReportId, string code, string studyId, string serverLocation)
{
    using (var transaction = _reportRepository.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
    {
        try
        {
            var record = new Report()
            {
                ConsultantReportId = consultantReportId,
                Code = code,
                StudyId = studyId,
                RequestedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ServerLocation = serverLocation
            };

            _reportRepository.Add(record);
            await _reportRepository.SaveAsync();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error("DB Transaction error, rolling back: " + e);
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}

The issue is once it attempts to insert a duplicate row, I would expect it to just roll it back and continue on. Instead, it seems to corrupt the repository instance and cause all future attempts to insert a record to fail with the same error.
That is to say:

Fail to insert row with ID 123, throws duplicate PK error (ID = 123) (currently expected)

Attempt to insert a completely different row with ID 456 afterwards, this also fails and throws duplicate PK error (ID = 123), this is the part I would not expect


This continues on for hours until eventually the error latches on to a different ID to fail with.
I recognize that the root of this issue should be to avoid inserting duplicates in the first place, and I am looking into that. But I still feel this piece of code should be robust enough to shrug off an error without failing all future inserts.
I've verified the way this method is written with the transaction rollback logic against numerous posts and articles and it seems like it should be right, but I must be missing something if this is happening. Any help is appreciated!

The transaction rollback clears up the database - but not the EF (EF Core?) db context. This db context will still contain that row with ID=123, possibly in the "Added" state, so the next time you call .SaveChanges() on the context, EF will try to insert that row again. Solutions? (1) discard the context and create a new one if such an error happens, or (2) if you're on EF Core 5.0 or higher, use dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear() to wipe the db context's "memory"

This is on Entity Framework 6.4.4. (Not Core), and the repository is initialized through dependency injection, would re-initializing every time there's an issue defeat the purpose of the DI pattern?

You could also try to reset that "offending" object's entity state to "Detached" - something like : context.Entry(yourObject).State = EntityState.Detached to just "clear out" that one offending object from your change tracker, without having to recreate your DbContext, or "flush" your entire change tracker

From what I read I conclude that the repository's life span is too long anyway. It's already telling that you need this transaction. If you'd have a new repository instance for each request you could simply leave transaction management to EF. Which lifetime is used in DI?

@marc_s Thank you, setting the record as detached seems to have worked, going to go with that for now.

@GertArnold It is added as Scoped, I think that's the answer you're asking for? And you may be right about the lifetime being too long, unfortunately tackling that would be a whole other beast of refactoring for another day as we have many repositories following the same pattern. Thank you for your insight!
